# MongoDb C# ToList() slow performance. Any way to improve?

Tags: c#, mongodb, performance

as the title says I found MongoDb C# Driver being very slow in term of data manifestation.

I have a collection with 1000 documents. They will not grow and I need to read a lot from this collection.
A simple query as

```
db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection_name")
  .Aggregate()
  .Match(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte("age", 30))
```

can found like 200 documents and with the explain plan of MongoDbCompass it is very fast.

The problem is when I need to manifest those 200 documents (with .ToList() or .ToListAsync()) it takes like **10 seconds**.
For 800 documents it takes **30 seconds**!
Ok maybe I don't need all of those because what I will show to the users is a paginated web page =>
so I added a Skip(n) and Limit(n + 20) but also with this limitation it takes **1.5 seconds** to manifest. It is a lot!

Each document weight 1kb, they all have 20 properties which one is an array of subdocuments. For now I am getting the data as BsonDocumet because I haven't yet decided the document structure.

So I am asking... is this the end of it? There is something I can do about it?

Thank you very much! T_T

**Edit**
I am using the latest C# MongoDb Driver (2.11.1)

**Edit2**
I have indexes in place for the properties I need to search for.
Also this result are from localhost:27017, so all in local.

Comment: Why are you calling `.Aggregate().Match(...)` and not just `.Find()` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I also do other operation, this is only the simple one. I made a dynamic aggregation pipeline which will do a lot of thing.
Are you telling me that if I use the Builders.Filter in the Find than the ToList will be faster?

Comment: I can't say for sure that it will make any difference, but they do do slightly different things I believe.

Comment: I tried with the FindSync() and the FindAsync() but the result in performance to manifest the data is the same as Aggregate().Match(...)

Comment: In that case, I'm assuming you don't have an index on "age".

Comment: Sorry I did not specify that I also have indexes on the properties I need to search.
The query is working fine for what I see in MongoDbCompass. It's the actual manifest of the data that took a lot.

Comment: OK in that case your connection to your server is slow.

Comment: I need to update my question with these information because what I am doing is all local.
I am using the db in localhos:27017 so I don't think is a connection issue.

Comment: @theramenboy , did you find the reason of your issue? I'm facing the same kind of problem :/